# What is the proper syntax for an UPDATE query in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have an sample query of what i want to do but the syntax is in MySQL.

```
 $sql = "UPDATE tbl_sample SET ".$column_name."='".$text."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
```

But it has to be done using Postgres syntax. And sorry, I'm just new at back-end programming.

here's the other src for some pages
main.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  function fetch_data()  
  {  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"dbselect.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#live_data').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
  }  
  fetch_data();  
  $(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function(){  
       var desc = $('#desc').text();  
       var ipadd = $('#ipadd').text();
       var port = $('#port').text();
       var platform = $('#platform').text();

       if(desc == '')  
       {  
            alert("Enter Description");  
            return false;  
       }  
       if(ipadd == '')  
       {  
            alert("Enter IP Address");  
            return false;  
       }

       if(port == '')  
       {  
            alert("Enter Port Number");  
            return false;  
       }

       if(platform == '')  
       {  
            alert("Enter DB Platform");  
            return false;  
       } 
       $.ajax({  
            url:"dbinsert.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{desc:desc, ipadd:ipadd, port:port, platform:platform},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data)  
            {  
                 alert(data);  
                 fetch_data();  
            }  
       }) 
  });  
  function edit_data(id, text, column_name)  
  {  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"dbedit.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data){  
                 alert(data);  
            }  
       });  
  }   $(document).on('blur', '.desc', function(){  
       var id = $(this).data("id1");  
       var desc = $(this).text();  
       edit_data(id, desc, "desc");  
  });  
  $(document).on('blur', '.ipadd', function(){  
       var id = $(this).data("id2");  
       var ipadd = $(this).text();  
       edit_data(id,ipadd, "ipadd");  
  });

  $(document).on('blur', '.port', function(){  
       var id = $(this).data("id3");  
       var port = $(this).text();  
       edit_data(id,port, "port");  
  });

  $(document).on('blur', '.platform', function(){  
       var id = $(this).data("id4");  
       var platform = $(this).text();  
       edit_data(id,platform, "platform");  
  });  

  $(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function(){  
       var id=$(this).data("id5");  
       if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"dbdelete.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{id:id},  
                 dataType:"text",  
                 success:function(data){  
                      alert(data);  
                      fetch_data();  
                 }  
            });  
       }  
    });  
 });
```

here's the insert query:

```
<?php  
   $connect = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=dbinv user=postgres          password=moira port=5432");  
   $sql = "INSERT INTO \"kbc\".dbinventory(desc,ipadd,port,platform)
   values ('".$desc."','".$ipadd."','".$port."','".$platform."')"; 
   if(pg_query($connect, $sql))  
   {  
  echo 'Data Inserted';  
   }  
  ?>
```

and the here's the edit query that I'm concerned about:

```
<?php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test_db");  
$id = $_POST["id"];  
$text = $_POST["text"];  
$column_name = $_POST["column_name"];  
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_sample SET ".$column_name."='".$text."' WHERE   id='".$id."'";  
if(pg_query($connect, $sql))  
{  
  echo 'Data Updated';  
}  
?>
```

The database is done but still doesnt work. Am i overlooking or did i miss something or is it all wrong?? Please kindly look at these src and tell me which should i reinforce/change.

Comment: I don't think a plain `UPDATE` has syntax in PSQL which is any different from most other databases.  Hence, I suspect that you have another problem.  So, what is the actual problem?

Comment: Right. This is missing pretty much every needed detail. PostgreSQL version, error message, client language/driver, ...

Comment: Sir @CraigRinger well uhm im doing a school project to be honest. So security doesnt really mean a thing. Im coding it in PHP with PSQL as my DB source

Comment: `psql` is the **command line client** of Postgres it does not have "a syntax". The database product is called PostgreSQL or simply Postgres.

Comment: @kevin That's the attitude that creates disastrous security in the real world. Security always means something. Avoiding teaching/learning it because it's harder leads to people taking the bad habits they learn initially into the workforce. In this case, though, it's also *easier* to do it right the first time, because of problems like the one you're probably experiencing here...

Comment: @CraigRinger that is true sir but i need to settle up first the main framework/foundation of my page before anything else.

Comment: and also im blind-doing the live table using ajax which i've followed some tutorials on youtube. let me edit my question and post the codes.

Comment: *"The database is done but still doesn't work."*. Well, do you check for errors anywhere? What's in the database server log? *Am i overlooking something?"*. Yes, failing to properly handle your input value quoting/escaping or using parameterised statements, per my answer. Fix it to use `pg_query_params` and check for errors, and if it still doesn't work, then it's worth looking deeper.

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem is that you're constructing your query dangerously wrong. Most likely `$text` or `$id` has a quote in it, or similar, so the statement lands up being invalid syntax.

e.g. if `$text` is `O'Reilly` you'll get:

```
ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Reilly"
```

Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

You haven't given any details about the tools/language/etc you're using, but you should use the query parameter binding ("prepared statement") support for your language and database driver.

Assuming you're using PHP, please read:

- http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php

Do **not** "fix" this with use of regular expressions for homebrew quoting, or with unsafe functions like PHP's `addslashes`.

If it worked in MySQL, I assume you were using it without the `ANSI QUOTES` option enabled, and `"double quoted"` identifiers. Or you're trying to escape with backslashes, like `'O\'Reilly'`, which *will not work* in an ANSI SQL compliant database. You must double the quotes, like `'O''Reilly'`, instead. But see above; don't do that, use bind parameters in prepared statements instead.